# xammp folder reuse on new harddrive/windows after crash

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp, localhost

I have xampp php 5.3.8 for windows which was installed on my pc on a dedicated folder,D:/XAMPP

It was being backed up as raw files to my network storage each while

Suddenly PC hard disk crashed, I replaced the harddisk and installed new windows, copied back the whole xampp folder but doesn't start from the xampp control panel, no response if tried to start apache or mysql

Any idea how i can make it work, it has a lot of databases already in there and several settings which I want to re-use in my new windows installation

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall services. From elevated command prompt (run as administrator) `cd` to `mysql` directory and run `mysql_installservice`. For Apache `cd` to `apache` directory and run `apache_installservice`. If this doesn't work, install XAMPP and copy data files manually.

Comment: i don't want to use it as a service, just to operate the apache and mysql on demand, it was this way on my older pc/windows. i tried that what you told me it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this need to copy entire xampp directory to different windows or PC...

1. download fresh copy (zip version) of the same version i.e. in my case was the php 5.3.8 so the xampp version was 1.7.7
2. unzip your package next to your old directory, and rename the old directory to something else
3. copy both htdocs and mysql folder to new xampp directory
4. IMPORTANT go to your php.ini and my.ini - update all paths to new directory location, in my case it was D:\xampp
5. run xampp_setup.bat again, it may show can't find php cli error press any key to continue.. ignore.. just press any key several times and it worked for me
6. abandon older directory or remove/archive it somewhere else

it worked for me so far seem ok, all databases seem ok

cheers